# How to handle "maybe-relationships"?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am writing a Symfony2 application based on Doctrine and MySql and I am stuck at a conceptual question:

A user can make a payment (=a `Payment` entity) which is possible via different methods. Each method requires different data and is thus a single entity itself. 
Between the entity `Payment` and the entities `CreditCard`, `Paypal`, `...` exists a one-to-one relationship. More precisely, each Payment has exactly one chosen option with the connected  payment method.

How should I implement that in doctrine?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe you could use inheritance : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html. Create a "Method" super class containing common properties. "CreditCard", "Paypal", etc will extend it whith their own properties.

Comment: that is what I have been looking for - thank you!